# Quotients of equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

Let $R,S$ and $T$ relations of equivalence in $A$ and suppose that $R\subset S\subset T$ prove that:

If $R \circ T$ is a relation of equivalence in $A$, then $(S/R)\circ (T/R) =(S\circ T)/R$

This is my work that I have done.

$$\begin{array}{crl}
 ([x]_R,[y]_R)\in (S/R)\circ (T/R) &\iff &\exists_z (x,z)\in(T/R) \wedge(z,y)\in (S/R) \\
  &\iff &\ (x,z) \in T \wedge (z,y) \in S \\
 &\iff&\ (x,y) \in S \circ T\\
 &\iff & ([x]_R,[y]_R) \in (S \circ T)/R
\end{array}$$

I appreciate your contributions with the definitions used.

Comment: Why is the first implication valid? What you possibly have showed is the inclusion $(S/R)\circ (T/R) \subseteq (S\circ T)/R.$ Have you thought of how to show the opposite inclusion so that you can conclude equality?

Comment: I used the composition definition, so what is your idea? @md2perpe

Comment: And why is the second implication valid? How are you using the quotient $/R$?

Comment: because this is the definition of composition and I think that you can use transitivity but I'm not sure @md2perpe .

Comment: How is the quotient relation $S/R$ defined?

Comment: $S/R=\{([x]_R,[y]_R) : (x,y) \in S\}$ @md2perpe

Comment: How did you use this definition in your proof of $(S/R)\circ (T/R) \subseteq (S\circ T)/R$?

Comment: It was my mistake but I think that now, I know how to solve the exercise @md2perpe.

Comment: Check my proof @md2perpe

Comment: Your second line should be: $\Rightarrow (\exists z)[ ([x]_R,[z]_R) \in T \land ([z]_R, [y]_R) \in S]$. It looks like all of the $\Rightarrow$s can be strengthened to $\iff,$ given that $R\subseteq S \subseteq T$.

Comment: $\iff $  You' re right. Maybe I don't understand this part why (∃z)[([x]R,[z]R)∈T∧([z]R,[y]R)∈S ? what is the definition? @BrianO

Comment: Oops I'm sorry, that should have been "$... \in T/R \land ... \in S/R$"

Comment: and then how to unravel the quotient set $T/R \wedge S/R $ to arrive at the composition $S \circ T$ ?

Comment: To be consistent you should write $\exists [z]_R,$ not $\exists z$:
$$([x]_R,[y]_R)\in (S/R)\circ (T/R) \iff \exists [z]_R\in A/R \text{ s.t. } ([x]_R,[z]_R)\in(T/R) \land ([z]_R,[y]_R)\in (S/R)$$

Comment: You need to be more precise with what kind of objects things are. Are they equivalence classes (i.e. in $A/R$) or are they objects directly in $A$? And how do you get from an object of one type to an object of another type?

Comment: How is it going?

Comment: I'm so confused md2perpe

Answer (score 1):

$$
([x]_R,[y]_R)\in (S/R)\circ (T/R) 
\\ \Updownarrow 1 \\
\exists [z]_R\in A/R \text{ s.t. } ([x]_R,[z]_R)\in(T/R) \land ([z]_R,[y]_R)\in (S/R)
\\ \Updownarrow 2 \\
\exists z\in A \text{ s.t. } (x,z)\in T \land (z,y)\in S
\\ \Updownarrow 3 \\
(x,y) \in S\circ T
\\ \Updownarrow 4 \\
([x]_R,[y]_R) \in (S \circ T)/R
$$

1. Definition of $\circ$.
2. Definition of quotient relations.
3. Definition of $\circ$.
4. Definition of quotient relations.

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I had @md2perpe